# Functional Programming exercise I can't figure out

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I've been looking at a problem for hours and failing to find a solution. I'm given an array of customer objects.

In each customer object is an array of friends.

In the array of friends is an object for each friend, containing some data, including a name key/value pair.

What I'm trying to solve for: I'm given this customers array and a customer's name. I need to create a function to find if this customer name is in any other customer's friend lists, and if so, return an array of those customer's names.

Below is a customer list. And as an example, one of the customers is Olga Newton. What the code should be doing is seeing that Olga Newton is a customer and is also in the friends lists of Regina and Jay, and should be returning an array of Regina and Jay.

I thought I could do this simply with a filter function, but because the friends list is an array with more objects, this is adding level of complexity for me I can't figure out.

Below is a customer array. The out put should be

```
['Regina', 'Jay']
```

and what I've gotten has either been

```
[{fullCustomerObj1}, {fullCustomerObj2}]
```

or

```
[ ]
```

What am I missing?

Here is the customer array:

```
    var customers = [{
name: "Olga Newton",
age: 43,
balance: "$3,400",
friends: [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Justice Lara"
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: "Duke Patrick"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Herring Hull"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Johnnie Berg"
}]
}, {
name: "Regina",
age: 53,
balance: "$4,000",
    friends: [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Cheryl Kent"
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: "Cynthia Wells"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Gutierrez Waters"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Olga Newton"
}]
}, {
name: "Jay",
age: 28,
balance: "$3,000",
friends: [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Cross Barnett"
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: "Raquel Haney"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Olga Newton"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Shelly Walton"
}]
}];
```

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74082753/i-need-to-find-how-many-friends-of-a-given-people-array-have-names-that-start-wi)?

Comment: "*what I've gotten*" - please [edit] your question to include the code you used to get the (wrong) results

Answer (score 1):

Use filter and map, please.

```
function friends(c, name){
    return c.filter((a) => {
        return a.friends.map(b => b.name).includes(name)
    }).map(a => a.name);
}
console.log(friends(customers, "Olga Newton"));

// ['Regina', 'Jay']
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

We look to an array (*friends[]*) inside anther (*customers[]*), So used two **for loops**, the first determine witch customer will look for his friends, and the second the array will search inside, then set **if statement** if the *cust name* is inside *friends[]*: adding the customer name to *customerFriends[]* array, At the end return the *customerFriends[]*.

```
   let cust = "Olga Newton"; // Get the customer name who you look for his friends.

      const findFriend = (cust, arrs) => { // Create findFriend function.
          let customerFriends = []; // Create an array to set the result to it.
          for (let i = 0; i < arrs.length; i++) { // For each Customer.
              for (const arr of arrs[i].friends) { // For each Friend.
                  if (arr.name === cust) { // Use Strict equality to find Customer name in friends[].
                      customerFriends.push(arrs[i].name); // Add the customer name to the customerFriends[].
                  }
              }
          }
          return customerFriends;// Return the final results.
      }

      console.log(findFriend(cust, customers)); // Call the function.
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, please add some description to your answer to show what you offer.